# Resharper build failed due to Code Analysis

Tags: wpf, msbuild, resharper

I'm using Resharper build with VS2013 to build my project
However, I noticed that some projects with Code Analysis turned on cannot be built using Resharped Build. The error is "Error: Code Anlysis detected errors. See Code Anlysis results window or log file for details". Clicking on it doesn't point me to where the problem is, and VS Code Analysis doesn't show any issue.
Those projects are build just fine with VS build.

Anyone has this problem? How do I disable Reshaper Build Code Analysis?

Answer (score 0):

When you view the Build Results (surprisingly enough in the Find Results window), by default, it filters down to just errors and warnings. If you use the filter drop-down in the toolbar, you can enable standard output from the build, too, so you'll be able to see all messages that are written during the build. This should allow you to see what's going wrong.

If there's an issue that Code Analysis (which I believe is a Visual Studio feature, right?) is reporting genuine errors and ReSharper Build isn't showing those in the build results, please could you [log an issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com)?

Alternatively, you can disable ReSharper Build for the specific projects in ReSharper's options dialog, on the Build page. Or, you can disable ReSharper Build for a specific solution - go to the Build options page, select use Visual Studio to build, and then click "Save To" to save to the shared solution settings file - the `.sln.dotSettings` file. You can then check this into source control for the whole team to share the settings.

Answer (score -1):

> How do I disable Reshaper Build Code Analysis?

1. Go to `RESHARPER` in the VS toolbar
2. Select `Options`
3. Expand `Code Inpsection` in the tree-view
4. Select `Settings`
5. Under **General**, uncheck `Enable code analysis`, click `Save`

Comment: The Code Analysis referred to in the question apparently is Visual Studio's own inspection rule set. That means, disabling ReSharper's code analysis doesn't solve the problem.